# How to convert multi-index DataFrames to GeoJSON FeatureCollections

Tags: python, mongodb, dataframe, geojson, multi-index

I have two `multi-index` `DataFrames` as follows.

- 1st `DataFrame`

[image]

- 2nd `DataFrame`

[image]

I would like to use the `DataFrames` above to construct `GeoJSON` `FeatureCollections` in the following format for each objects, and then insert them into `MongoDB`.

```
# GeoJSON
# Loop over all Object IDs

object[i] = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            # 1st DataFrame
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {},
            "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[·,·],[·,·],[·,·],...]]}
        },
        {
            # 2nd DataFrame
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {},
            "geometry": {"type": "LineString", "coordinates": [[·,·],[·,·],[·,·],...]}
        }
    ]
}

# MongoDB
# Loop over all Object IDs

from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient()
db = client.object
result = db.object.insert_one(object[i])
```

Since the **point number** of a specific object is **random**, and the **point numbers** of features `Polygon` and `LingString` in the same `FeatureCollection` are **not** necessarily **equal** to each other, it is hard to use `for` loop to achieve that goal. Could anyone come up with an idea on this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If "point number" means "number of points in each Feature", then this should work:

```
# transform to hierarchical series of [lat, lon]
s1 = df1.apply(lambda row: pd.concat([row['lat'], row['lon']]).tolist())
# now group that series by object id into a series of lists
coords1 = s1.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda s : s.tolist())
```

And the same for df2 -> s2. This yields `[[lat_0, lon_0], [lat_1, lon_1], ...]`, which is a a LineString.
To make df1 -> s1 into a geojson Polygon's coordinates list/array, you'll need to wrap each member list of coordinates in another list. See [RFC 7946 section 3.1.6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946#section-3.1.6) for the rules on Polygon coordinates. Finally, you'll have to wrap all that in a Polygon/Geometry in a Feature in a FeatureCollection.  If that seems like a lot of writing, consider importing the `geojson` extension of the `json` library.

I've built a more general function to aggregate pandas to geometries in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/SKalt/79c747681da506e5cd42699d054da849).